# Run Web Browser with specific WebGL / GLSL version

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'd like to run some tests to make sure some scenes I'm making will render on devices that only support WebGL 1.0. Is there a way to run a browser such that the browser only uses WebGL version 1.0 when it runs a WebGL scene?

I have already added `version 100` to the top of my shaders--is that all that's required, or is there more required to ensure one is testing a scene using WebGL 1.0? Any pointers others can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `version 100` on top of shaders does nothing.

If you created the context with `canvas.getContext('webgl')` you will get the basic WebGL 1 features.

When using WebGL 1 the shaders that have `#version 300 es` will fail to compile and a lot of features will be locked behind extensions.

You should look up which extensions are supported by your target browser and only enable those extensions during your tests.

But I would still strongly recommend testing on your target browsers, because the WebGL spec has a fairly relaxed requirement for what are the minimal features that are required to be supported.

I often see that some combinations of parameters work on some browsers and not on others, even if those browsers support WebGL 2.

Comment: Ah thanks @zoran404. I think I'm going to need more devices :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using some kind of library? If you're doing raw WebGL then if you ask for "webgl" you always get webgl1. if you ask for "webgl2" you get webgl2 if the device supports it but it does **not** automatically fall back to WebGL1 as the 2 APIs are similar but incompatible.

As for shaders WebGL1 only supports GLSL ES 1.0. WebGL2 supports GLSL ES 1.0 and GLSL ES 3.0.

That's it.

If you want an idea of what features are supported across devices see [webglstats.com](https://webgstats.com). The minimum features are defined in the spec but very few devices support the minimum and if there are any devices that support the minimum they are likely going to have serious performance issues.

Comment: the context creation logic is super helpful to know!